# Javascript variable value using an if statement

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables, if-statement

I'm new here and to **Javascript** so please be gentle!

I've a **Html** form which I've successfully scripted to look up stores from my **SQL** database and pin point on a google map within a chosen radius to the users postcode.

There is a free text field for the user to type in their postcode and two list boxes, one for pre-set radius values and another for pre-set store types.

My code works fine if store type `Type1` or `Type2` is selected but I want the user to be able to select `All` and it return both `Type1` and `Type2` on the map.

The obvious thing to me is to have an if statement within the searchUrl variable (below) that says if `All` is selected then use the url without the `+ '&BusinessType=' + businesstypechoice` part on the end, else use the existing url.

However much I've tried to write the if statement I can't get the form/map to work, it doesn't return any values.

How do I write the if statement correctly or is there a better approach?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="addressInput"  placeholder="Enter Postcode" size="13"/>
<select id="radiusSelect">
<option value="10" >10 mi</option>
<option value="25" selected>25 mi</option>
<option value="50" >50 mi</option>
<option value="100">100 mi</option>
<option value="200">200 mi</option>
</select>

<select id="businesstypeSelect">
<option value="All" selected>All</option>
<option value="Type 1" >Type 1</option>
<option value="Type 2" >Type 2</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onClick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
```

**Javascript** (*the part from the function which I believe is relevant here*)

```
 var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
 var businesstypechoice = document.getElementById('businesstypeSelect').value;     
 var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?Latitude=' + center.lat() + '&Longitude=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius + '&BusinessType=' + businesstypechoice;
 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
```

The function continues on. Let me know if you need to see more of it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

My latest attempt at an if statement:

```
 var searchUrl;
 if(businesstypechoice == 'All') {
 searchurl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?Latitude=' + center.lat() + '&Longitude=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;} else
 if(businesstypechoice != 'All') {
 searchurl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?Latitude=' + center.lat() + '&Longitude=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius + '&BusinessType=' + businesstypechoice;}
 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
```

The first section of the phpsqlsearch_genxml.php file.

```
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["Latitude"];
$center_lng = $_GET["Longitude"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];
$business_type = $_GET["BusinessType"];
```

I think I need an if statement for the $business_type variable to tell it not to look up the BusinessType when 'All' is selected because'All' doesn't exist in the BusinessType column in my SQL database.

Comment: Your solution looks fine. Can you provide code with described if statement? Also let as know does `phpsqlsearch_genxml.php` file is written by you or provided by third-party? Problem may reside in that file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

The php file was written by a 3rd party originally but I've modified it to fit my system.

The first section of the php file is:

    // Get parameters from URL
    $center_lat = $_GET["Latitude"];
    $center_lng = $_GET["Longitude"];
    $radius = $_GET["radius"];
    $business_type = $_GET["BusinessType"];

So I guess you've pointed me in the right direction. I'm now thinking my if statement was working ok but I need to use a second php file without the business_type section it it as I'm not passing a value when I select 'All' from the list box.

Thanks

Comment: You are right. But no need to write a separate file for that case. Just use if statement to add part related to $business_type into sql query, only when $business_type has value.

Answer (score 4):

Can you debug on the server and see what data you're getting through the querystring? The issue could be with with your server side code as well.

That said I'm a big fan of ternary operators.

```
var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
var businesstypechoice = document.getElementById('businesstypeSelect').value;     
var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?Latitude=' + center.lat() + '&Longitude=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' +     radius;

searchUrl = (businesstypechoice === "All") ? searchUrl : searchUrl + '&BusinessType=' + businesstypechoice;

 downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
```

This is the same thing as saying "if `businesstypechoice` equals all then return `searchUrl`, else return `searchUrl` plus the new query parameters.

Also be mindful of your camel casing. `Businesstypechoice` should be `businessTypeChoice`

Comment: +1 for the ternary operator, was just about to say the same thing.